# Simplify edge by Douglas–Peucker

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing, image-recognition

### Edge Detection

I have used `Soble` operator to get some useful points.Here is my al:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < mWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mHeight; y++) {
            int grayX = getGrayPoint(x + 1, y - 1) + 2 * getGrayPoint(x + 1, y) + getGrayPoint(x + 1, y + 1) -
                    (getGrayPoint(x - 1, y - 1) + 2 * getGrayPoint(x - 1, y) + getGrayPoint(x - 1, y + 1));
            int grayY = (getGrayPoint(x - 1, y + 1) + 2 * getGrayPoint(x, y + 1) + getGrayPoint(x + 1, y + 1)) -
                    (getGrayPoint(x - 1, y - 1) + 2 * getGrayPoint(x, y - 1) + getGrayPoint(x + 1, y - 1));
            int gradient = (int) Math.sqrt(grayX * grayX + grayY * grayY);
            if (gradient > 40){
                mEdgePoints.add(new int[]{x,y});
            }
        }
    }
```

### Simplify Edge

I know Douglas–Peucker al can help me simplify edge , however the key is that the sequence of edge points.

[Douglas–Peucker](http://karthaus.nl/rdp/)

**So how can I use Douglas–Peucker al?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before simplifying you have to join edge points in continuous chain.

The most important part of well-known [Canny algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) is edge tracking, so you might learn this algo and apply used approaches.

Comment: Sobel is preliminary stage - it just allows to determine large-gradient points. They are not linked together yet

Comment: Thanks! I found another algo :edge drawing a combined real-time edge and segment detector